# Mouseflow tracking returns anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I have some tracking code in JavaScript I am trying to run:

```
var _mfq = _mfq || [];
(function() {
   var mf = document.createElement("script"); mf.type = "text/javascript"; mf.async = true;
   mf.src = "//cdn.mouseflow.com/projects/e6773f1b-2981-4981-8245-a33c00dfe7ce.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(mf);
})();
```

However, the debugger in Chrome says there is an anonymous function by:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(mf);
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't append it in head try this instead

```
document.body.appendChild(mf);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var _mfq = _mfq || [];
   (function() {
       var mf = document.createElement("script"); mf.type = "text/javascript"; mf.async = true;
       mf.src = "//cdn.mouseflow.com/projects/e6773f1b-2981-4981-8245-a33c00dfe7ce.js";
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(mf);
   })();
}
```